# Vendor CSS stylesheets in Rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, precompile

I use Twitter [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) (not that that matters but it's a **third party** CSS file). Because it's a third party CSS "library" it should go in `/vendor/assets/stylesheets`. So far so good.

Now, I would like to concatenate all CSS in one application.css in production using the Rails 3.1(.1) asset pipeline and that's where I get stuck.

When I run `rake assets:precompile` it works as advertised. The Rake task creates a few application.css files in the `public/assets` folder with the digest and all. Problem is this file only contains the CSS from my CSS files in `/app/assets/stylesheets` and completely ignores the one in my vendor assets folder.

Does anyone know what I miss here and how I can tell Rails to concatenate the vendor stylesheet together with the app one(s)? Also, is it enough to only include:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

in the view (as I expect everything to be in one file in the end) or should I include every single CSS file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have exactly your configuration, it works fine. Are you sure you're requiring bootstrap in your application.css? Like:

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*= require_self
*/
```

Comment: I had a second application.css in my vendor assets folder to include the bootstrap CSS but I needed to include it in the main app assets application.css. Thought I had to separate them. Thanks for helping me out!